# How to convert this MD5 encode PHP to java

Tags: java, php, md5

I have simply code in PHP like that

```
$hash = md5("testtesttest", TRUE);
echo $hash.'<br>';
$hash = md5($hash . "test", TRUE);
echo $hash.'<br>';
```

With 2 line fisrt in java, it's working good with my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String str = new String(md5x16("test"));
        byte[] input = md5x16("testtesttest");
        String t = new String(input);
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    public static byte[] md5x16(String text) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digester.update(text.getBytes());
            byte[] md5Bytes = digester.digest();
            return md5Bytes;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But in line 3 and 4 in PHP, I can't do the same in Java
If I parse to String and add a "test" to it, I will get another result with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iraklis should be right. md5() gives you a hex-encoded output string by default. You only get the unencoded bytes like in Java by passing in TRUE for the optional $raw_output argument.

> the lengths range from 29 to 32

```
hexString.append( Integer.toHexString(0xFF & message[ i ] ) );
function makeBrokenMD5($s) {
$hash= md5($s, TRUE);
$bytes= preg_split('//', $hash, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$broken= '';
foreach ($bytes as $byte)
    $broken.= dechex(ord($byte));
return $broken;
```

}`